# Firebase Cloud Function - Promises : Is there any limitation to the number of 'promises' that can be added to Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So the Promise.all() does make out lives simpler.

But is there any limitation on the number of promises that can be added to 'Promise.all()'

i.e. Is there any **limitation on the size of the array 'promises'** in the following code:-

```
const promises = [];

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {

        **some code**

        promises.push(
            docRef.set(newData, {merge: true})
        );

    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
```

**----------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Further Clarification:**

I'm using this Cloud Function to update all users on my App.

Model DB Structure: `Users/userId`

Since the number of users is small, I'm not facing any issues for now.

But, **as the number of users grows** I'm concerned if I may hit some limits..

And as per the issues pointed out by:

1) [david](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423491/david) - browser's maximum concurrent web requests slowing things down

2) [herohtar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574531/herohtar) - limited memory available to your function

These two issues suggest that, there might as well be some limits.

So, can anyone point to the official doc for the same 
or
Anyone from the Firebase team, if you guys can throw some light on the same.

Comment: There may be a limit, but it will be very very large, way larger than you would ever hit. You're more likely to run into other problems, like the browser's maximum concurrent web requests slowing things down. Why are you asking? Just curiosity or do you have an actual issue?

Comment: Since you're talking about Firebase Cloud Functions, there is the possibility of hitting some limit due to the limited memory available to your function, unless you've allocated it more than the default.

Comment: @Herohtar - thanks for pointing the memory issue. working on it right now. 

Comment: @david - Is there any official reference for the 'max concurrent web request' issue? OR Is there anything I can do to tackle that issue?

Comment: Not specifically on Promises but you can batch writes to Firestore. Makes life easier https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: @ДмитроБулах: I thought about using batch writes, but doesn't that have a limit of 499, or something like that? 

Comment: yes, but you can use `PromiseAll([batch1, batch2, batch3... ])` to keep your load managable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this function has to scale up to massive numbers of users, you are almost certainly going to have more issues exceeding the limits of memory and time in your function before you exceed any limits on the number of promises.  I strongly suggest carefully thinking if you really want to load and perform N tasks in a function where N can be very large.  This is not the sort of thing Cloud Functions was made for.

If you really need to perform N tasks in a scalable way, and you must use Cloud Functions, consider breaking your work up into manageable, predictable sizes, and shard the work out to multiple function invocations.

Comment: Thanks this was what I was looking for. Can you please give me an approximate number on the max N for which the cloud function can be used for? (So, that the task executes with a minimal number of Function invocations)

Comment: No, I can't, because each item of work and its memory requirements could vary drastically, given that your question was not very specific about any of that.  I suggest performing your own benchmarking or tests give your own actual scenario.